# Bypass CORS to post form to external domain but redirect to another page

Tags: javascript

I've been trying for a few weeks to bypass CORS and then redirect to a new webpage but I'm not having success.

I configured `Program.cs` to bypass CORS and success:

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                     policy =>
                     {
                         policy.WithOrigins("https://myPage.com.ar")
                         .AllowAnyOrigin()
                         .AllowAnyMethod()
                         .AllowAnyHeader();                         
                     });
});

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

Now, after submiting the form, I want to redirect to a new View, one that I create it called "ThanksPage", a custom view. For this I'm trying to do it by `Javascript`.

If I don't redirect to "ThanksPage", the form is submited correctly but redirects me to an external webpage. If I want a redirect to my custom view, I have CORS failure.

With Javascript:

Create an `EventListener` to the "submit buttons":

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
    form1 .addEventListener("submit", onSubmit);

    let formularioSAC = document.getElementById('form2');
    form2.addEventListener("submit", onSubmit);

    let formularioLFD = document.getElementById('form3');
    form3.addEventListener("submit", onSubmit);
}
```

And here is where I have the error:

```
const onSubmit = async ({ target }) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = new FormData(this);
    const response = await fetch(target.action, {
        method: target.method,
        body: form,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://myPage.com.ar/Home/Index'
        }
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        console.log('OK');
        target.reset();
        await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res({ ok: window.location.href = 'http://myPage.com.ar:5002/Home/ThanksPage' }), 2000));
    } else {
        console.log('Not OK');
    }
};
```

I think that the problem is that I'm trying to send again the `form` with this code, the only thing I want is redirect to my custom page.

> Access to fetch at 'https://externalPage.com' from origin 'http://myPage.com.ar' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
> at HTMLFormElement.onSubmit

**EDIT**

I added to `mode: 'no-cors'` as is suggested in the post that is in "duplicated", and now is appears that the fetch is working but returns `false` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header):

**Opaque responses (no-cors mode)**

Sometimes you need to make an HTTP request, but you don't need to read the response. e.g. if you are posting a log message to the server for recording.

If you are using the fetch API (rather than XMLHttpRequest), then you can configure it to not try to use CORS.

Note that this won't let you do anything that you require CORS to do. You will not be able to read the response. You will not be able to make a request that requires a preflight.

It will let you make a simple request, not see the response, and not fill the Developer Console with error messages.

How to do it is explained by the Chrome error message given when you make a request using fetch and don't get permission to view the response with CORS:

> Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/' from origin 'https://example.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Thus:

```
fetch("http://example.com", { mode: "no-cors" });
```

[image]

Body: null

Comment: What does the error look like?

Comment: There I shoed the error.

Comment: Putting `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://myPage.com.ar/Home/Index'` on the **request** is nonsense (you can't give yourself permission to access other origins) and makes the request preflighted. This appears to be your problem as the the error message says that `externalpage.com` is rejected the preflight request.

Comment: @Quentin I added a `mode: 'no-cors'` as is suggested in the link that says I'm duplicated, and now the `response.ok` is `false`.

Comment: @BilbitBolson — When you say "as suggested" do you mean the bit which starts out by saying "Sometimes you need to make an HTTP request, but you **don't** need to read the response" and also says "You will not be able to read the response."

Comment: "As suggested" I was referring to the answer that it was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: @BilbitBolson — Yes, as it says, since you want to read the response (the status code is part of the response) that is **absolutely unsuitable** for your needs.

Comment: @Quentin and how do I know if the form was submited successfully?

Comment: If you make the request directly from the client and don’t have permission (e.g. via CORS) to read the response… you can’t.